# не могу понять синтаксис ajax кода

Tags: jquery, ajax

Не могу разобраться что за синтаксис. Вот есть такой кусок кода:

```
var ajax_post="/admin/ajax/send/";
 $(".form .button a").click(function(){
$context=$(this).closest("form");
name_obj=$context.find("[name=name]");
phone_obj=$context.find("[name=number]");
datago=$context.find("[name=check_form]");
phone_val=phone_obj.val();
if(datago.is(":checked")){
    if(phone_val)
      {
          if(!loading)
             {
                 loading=true;
                 records=[];
                 records.push({
                     phone:phone_val,mango:$("header .phone a").text(),site:window.location.hostname,mail:$("[name=mail]").val()});
                     if(name_obj.length>0)
             if((tn=name_obj.val().trim())!='')
        records[0]['name']=tn;
    $.post(ajax_post,{
        op:'record',
        args:{record:records}},
        function(data){loading=false;console.log(data);
        phone_obj.removeClass('error');
        $context.hide();
        $context.next(".thank-you").show();});}}
```

Это простая форма отправки, мне не понятны вот эти строки

`op:'record',
            args:{record:records}},`
Не знаю что написать в обработчике формы что бы вытянуть данные из массива records. Переписывать не предлагать, хочу разобраться как это работает.

Comment: А что именно не понятно в этих строках, это данные которые передаются на сервер. И куда ты хочешь вытягивать данные из массива?

Comment: Из массива нужно передать в базу данных, я не знаю как задать переменные для дальнейшей обработки

Comment: у тебя в `args:{record:records}` передается объект с массивом `records`, по этому адресу передается запрос `/admin/ajax/send/`, странно что указан путь к директории, должен быть файл в котором как раз ты сможешь обработать полученные данные и сделать что тебе нужно

Comment: Еще не совсем пойму, зачем класть объект в массив, а потом опять пихать это в объект, чтобы просто передать один параметр в `args`. Вот этот момент лучше переделать, значимости он вроде ни какой не несет, а вот вытаскивать данные из такой вложенности не очень удобно)

Comment: Если указана дирректория, значит название файла будет index.php, это никак не влияет на мой вопрос, так же я не писал, что не знаю что файл обрабатывается на строне сервера. Вложенности никакой нет, это массив, предполагаю, что json. Попробую вывести в консоль и посмотреть что там. Просто в формате ajax не указан тип данных, понятно, что он отправляется методом пост. Это простой пример который я могу переделать под другой синтаксис, но мне нужно понять как тут отправляются данные, т.к есть скрипт, который передает большое количество данных данным методом. В учебниках не нашел таких примеров.

Comment: наверно я тебя не совсем понял, этот массив же создается выше и в нем лежит объект в котором сохраняются некоторые данные из формы и адрес страницы

Comment: Да, мне понятны какие данные там лежат, мне не понятно как их извлечь, если например я пишу  $name = $_POST['name']; то данные не приходят, если пишу так $name = $_POST['records:name']; то строка в бд создается но данные пустые

Comment: ну так у тебя эти данные и не отправляются на сервер, по этому ты и не можешь их обработать, обработай сначала что приходит $args = $_POST['args'], в $args у тебя будет вот этот объект `{record:records}`, ну а из него уже вытаскивай нужные данные

Comment: Данные отправляются вот так  Object
mail: undefined
mango: "+7 (987) 654-32-10"
name: "Вася"
phone: "+7 (987) 654-32-10"
site: "www.site.ru"

Comment: серелизовал args массив и записал в базу, получил такую конструкцию a:1:{
s:6:"record";a:1:{
i:0;a:4:{s:5:"phone";s:16:"+7(767)687-67-68";s:5:"mango";s:18:"+7 (987) 654-32-10";s:4:"site";s:11:"www.site.ru";s:4:"name";s:9:"User";}}} дальше понимаю что нужно пройтись foreach но не знаю как, может есть еще какой способ вытащить  переменные из record?

Comment: Я тебе по этому и говорил, перепиши этот момент и не мучайся, у тебя сейчас получается объект в котором по ключу record лежит массив в котором лежит объект, а в нем уже все данные, для чего такая вложенность я не пойму. Создай просто объект records и запихай в него все данные потом передай просто вот так `args: records`, получишь один объект со всеми данными, а там по ключу чего хочешь, то и дергай.

Comment: Да, без вашей подсказки не догадался бы сам, знаний не хватает. В общем убрал из кода record и args,  отправляю только массив records , но он все равно получается вложенным, конструкция после сериализации получается такая a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"phone";s:16:"+7(677)656-65-76";s:5:"mango";s:18:"7 (987) 654-32-10";s:4:"site";s:11:"www.site.ru";s:4:"name";s:7:"User";}}  данные по прежнему не могу вытащить по ключу

Comment: Вложенным он получается еще выше когда создается, а потом в него помещается объект. Вместо массива создай сразу объект с нужными данными. [вот так](https://hastebin.com/iqufeqifiv.js)

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
op:'record',
args:{record:records}}
```

Подозреваю, что `op`, это обозначение операции. `args` - её параметры. В данном случае параметр всего один.

> Не знаю что написать в обработчике формы что бы вытянуть данные из
>   массива records

Для этого вначале нужно понять, из чего этот массив состоит. Ответ в приведённом Вами коде:

```
records.push({phone:phone_val,mango:$("header .phone a").text(),site:window.location.hostname,mail:$("[name=mail]").val()});
```

Для большей наглядности всегда можно вывести сформированный массив в консоль браузера.

А, дальше, поняв структуру массива вытаскиваете на стороне сервера нужные данные.

Comment: Ответ не несет полезной информации